# ArgoCD error: roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io already exists

Tags: argocd, gitops

ArgoCD seems to be trying to reconcile a role that doesn't exist, in an infinite loop. This message gets spammed out faster than I can read it.

Using OLM, I get this output.

`1.6853705979268556e+09  INFO    controller.argocd       Reconciling ArgoCD      {"reconciler group": "argoproj.io", "reconciler kind": "ArgoCD", "name": "bionic-finger-argocd", "namespace": "admin", "namespace": "admin", "name": "bionic-finger-argocd"} 1.6853705979269025e+09  INFO    controller_argocd       reconciling SSO 1.685370597927047e+09   INFO    controller_argocd       Delete Keycloak deployment for ArgoCD bionic-finger-argocd in namespace admin 1.685370597928096e+09   INFO    controller_argocd       Using default resource tracking method 'label' 1.685370597930523e+09   INFO    controller_argocd       reconciling status 1.6853705980700514e+09  INFO    controller_argocd       reconciling roles 1.685370598070095e+09   INFO    controller_argocd       creating role bionic-finger-argocd-argocd-application-controller for Argo CD instance bionic-finger-argocd in namespace admin 1.6853705980742722e+09  INFO    controller_argocd       roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "bionic-finger-argocd-argocd-application-controller" already exists 1.6853705980743098e+09  ERROR   controller.argocd       Reconciler error        {"reconciler group": "argoproj.io", "reconciler kind": "ArgoCD", "name": "bionic-finger-argocd", "namespace": "admin", "error": "roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io \"bionic-finger-argocd-argocd-application-controller\" already exists"} sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).processNextWorkItem /go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.11.0/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:266 sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).Start.func2.2 /go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.11.0/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:227 1.6853705980743408e+09  INFO    controller.argocd       Reconciling ArgoCD      {"reconciler group": "argoproj.io", "reconciler kind": "ArgoCD", "name": "bionic-finger-argocd", "namespace": "admin", "namespace": "admin", "name": "bionic-finger-argocd"} 1.685370598074919e+09   INFO    controller_argocd       reconciling SSO 1.6853705980754066e+09  INFO    controller_argocd       Delete Keycloak deployment for ArgoCD bionic-finger-argocd in namespace admin 1.6853705980768454e+09  INFO    controller_argocd       Using default resource tracking method 'label' 1.6853705980790741e+09  INFO    controller_argocd       reconciling status`

The only pod OLM will spin up is Dex, otherwise the logs are just filled with the above.

Has anyone come across this?

I tried wiping minikube and reinstalling a few times, but it's persisting.